# Thread pool run in order

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have two integers x and y. x is the number of threads in thread pool. y is the number of times I want to run threads. I don't want to use sleep().

```
public class TestThreadPool { 

  public static void main(String[] args) {  

    int x = 7;
    int y = 1000;

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(x);//creating a pool of 7 threads  

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {  

       Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + (y-i));  
       executor.execute(worker); 
     }  

    executor.shutdown();  

    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {   }  

   System.out.println("Finished all threads");  
 }  
}

class WorkerThread implements Runnable {  

    private String message;  

    public WorkerThread(String s){  
        this.message=s;  
    }  

    public void run() {       
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" count = " + message);     
    }     
}
```

When I run this, I get this -->

```
pool-1-thread-1 count = 1000
pool-1-thread-3 count = 998
pool-1-thread-2 count = 999
pool-1-thread-4 count = 997
.
.
.
.
pool-1-thread-2 count = 2
pool-1-thread-15 count = 1
pool-1-thread-14 count = 7
pool-1-thread-4 count = 8
pool-1-thread-3 count = 9
Finished all threads
```

My problem is: I want output, threads and count in order.
Like this -->

```
pool-1-thread-1 count = 1000
pool-1-thread-2 count = 999
pool-1-thread-3 count = 998
pool-1-thread-4 count = 997
pool-1-thread-5 count = 996
pool-1-thread-6 count = 995
pool-1-thread-7 count = 994
pool-1-thread-1 count = 993
pool-1-thread-2 count = 992
.
.
pool-1-thread-5 count = 2
pool-1-thread-6 count = 1
Finished all threads
```

Comment: If you want everything to run synchronously, it isn't clear what the purpose of the thread pool is. Nothing can run in parallel your way.

Comment: This isn't how concurrency works

Comment: I will never for the life of me understand why people use threads when they want sequential execution.

Comment: The question is why, what is so important in thread n that force thread n+1 to wait for him ?

Answer (score 1):

Your WorkerThread objects are run by different threads in the thread pool.  The threads run independently, so some may finish running a worker faster, and some slower.  That's why the numbers are not coming out in order.

If you want the numbers to be in order, the easiest way is just to run them all in your main thread, rather than using a thread pool.  Alternatively, you could create an ExecutorService with a fixed thread pool with only one thread in it.

Answer (score 1):

So you have the problem that you are ***not*** getting `y` decremented ***in order***.

The reason is very straight forward. You expect that the thread starting first, should be finished as first. But in thread execution, such a thing is ***not guaranteed***.

It all depends on how each thread getting allocated for resources.

As per your requirement, what you all need is a ***sequential program, not parallel***. A parallel program with threads, is completely irrelevant in your case.

Hope this helps. :))

Comment: can you show me how to do it with or without threadpool. eample program link or something.

Comment: @Mahela.Prasad if you just want to see decrementing, just run a for loop from 1000 to 0.

Comment: @Supun.Wijerathne i want to use x number of threads for that. I thought threadpool is good for it. i dont know how to do without it.

Comment: @Mahela.Prasad I think you have seen EJP's comment on your question.  ;) here what I have to say is the similar thing. If you really want to use threads, wait I'll update my answer with a sample code, once i got time. :))